# How to create repeated task on Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am looking for a way to run on test that would do several uploads and check whether the file type is accepted or invalid in webdriver C#.

The reason for this is, I need to check if ALL the files I uploaded are accepted by the site. So far I am only able to upload one file but I will like to do a loop that checks the uploaded file and accept or reject it then move on to upload the next file and so on. All in one test. So far I can only upload just one file:

```
public UploadPage HTUpload()
    {
        int retryCount = 0;
        while (true && retryCount < Constants.RETRY_COUNT)
        {
            try
            {
                _driver.FindElement(By.Name("files[]")).SendKeys("C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\Desktop\\\\Capture.JPG");
                return this;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebDriverTimeoutException || ex is TimeoutException)
            {
                retryCount++;
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are only uploading a single file and the path is hard coded. You would need to change your method to accept a file path and then attempt to upload that file.

There are a few other issues that should be fixed

1. `while (true &&`

   I'm not sure why you have `true &&` in your `while`. That should be removed.
2. You shouldn't need the sleep after the timeouts occur. There's already likely been a long timeout period, there doesn't seem to be a need to wait even longer.

Here's the updated code with my suggestions

```
public UploadPage HTUpload(string filePath)
{
    int retryCount = 0;
    while (retryCount < Constants.RETRY_COUNT)
    {
        try
        {
            _driver.FindElement(By.Name("files[]")).SendKeys(filePath);
            return this;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebDriverTimeoutException || ex is TimeoutException)
        {
            retryCount++;
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this may sound like a silly question but where do I pass the corresponding argument to filepath"?. Also another question, any reason why the code I had already works in Chrome and Firefox but not on IE11?

Comment: You would call `HTUpload("C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\Desktop\\\\Capture.JPG")` or similar. Not sure why it wouldn't work in IE.